# Crontab definition for alternating jobs

Tags: cron

I want to schedule two jobs in which:
Job A runs every 4 hours from 00:40am
Job B runs every hours from 01:40am but skip to run on the hour the Job A runs, for instance:

`00:40am : jobA
01:40am : jobB
02:40am : jobB
03:40am : jobB
04:40am : jobA
05:40am : jobB
06:40am : jobB
07:40am : jobB
08:40am : jobA`
and so on...

Then should I define two crontab definitions:
`40 0/4 * * *` for jobA
`40 1-3,5-7,9-11,13-15,17-19,21-23 * * *` for jobB

Is there any better way to define jobB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[40 1/4,2/4,3/4 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#40_1/4,2/4,3/4_*_*_*) for jobB is probably easier to read next to the schedule for jobA, making it more obvious that jobA isn't running at the same time as jobB.